# Join two tables in mysql and show answer in table

Tags: php, mysql, join, left-join

[image]

Here is my table. By joining first 2 table i need answer in php as in third table

I tried query

```
            $sql="SELECT 
                ROUND(duct1.length * duct2.duct_63, 1) as d1, 
                ROUND(duct1.length * duct2.duct_125, 1) as d2,
                ROUND(duct1.length * duct2.duct_250, 1) as d3, 

                FROM duct1 JOIN duct2";
```

By values repeating. Please help me..

Comment: You need an `ON` clause.

Comment: I tried on clause first itself but didnt find accurate value

Answer (score 1):

A JOIN query goes like this.

```
SELECT
   (field1, field2, field3)
FROM table1
JOIN fieldname
ON table1.field1 = table2.field1
WHERE fieldname = $fieldname
```

Maybe this will help you?

Comment: That i know. But i cant use sum .

Comment: Try to make the sum in the php script and set that in a variable, and ask that variable in the query.

Comment: Then i have to use for loop so m any times. its not fair

Comment: I don't know what your code is so I can't answer to that, there is always an easyer way.